# Which AS suits better with EJB-2 application and the client code will reside in tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, jboss, ejb

I am new to EJB.I want do some experiment with EJB2.I a have installed tomcat 6 as container.
I am able to build simple web application with it.Now I want to develop a client which will reside in the tomcat and interact  with EJB which will reside in Jboss AS.

Please tell me from where to download the Application server and which version? 
I am using eclipse Galileo as IDE.

I do need to know how to configure my tomcat with  App server.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [JBoss 7.1 (community edition)](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) and definitely use **EJB-3** instead of **EJB-2**.

Answer (score 2):

Believe me, you *do not* want to experiment with EJB 2. Avoid that stuff like the plague!

If you want to experiment with EJB, use
EJB 3. This is a completely different technology that doesn't try to push you into insanity.

JBoss AS 7.1 or GlassFish 3.1 are good servers to start with.